# Where Windows store the files which are deleted during Ctrl+Z operation in folder in which the photos has been copied in?

Tags: android, photos, recycle-bin, recovery

I connected my Android to Windows 10 and cut-pasted all the pictures from Android into my C:/AndroidMedia/Pictures_2021_07_22 folder. I disconnected Android (which had free memory, of course) and I accidentally executed Ctrl+Z inside Pictures_2021_07_22 folder and all the pictures were deleted. They are not in the Recycle Bin. Where Windows Store those deleted pictures and how can I recover them?

I would be unimaginable that they are gone without even a confirmation message and without recovery option.

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl`+`Y` (redo).

Comment: When I move files via cut & paste like pictures from a device connect via MTP the undo function is not available and Ctrl+Z does nothing.